# Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<Response>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to fetch data from Facebook. The http.get() return data of type Future<http.Response>. This data is passed to second function where the data is converted to strings us jsonDecode function. My code return code returns error **type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'String'** at runtime.

How to return variable graphResponse in my code, which is a Future<http.Response> and pass it on to jsonExtractor Function. The below

```
class FetchFB {

  final String url;
  final String token;

  FetchFB({@required this.url, @required this.token});

  Future<http.Response> fetchData() async {
    http.Response graphResponse = await http.get('$url$token');
    print(graphResponse);
    return graphResponse;
  }

  dynamic jsonExtractor(dynamic dataResponse) async {
    return await jsonDecode(dataResponse);
  }
}
```

Inside main.dart

```
    String url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/me?fields=';
        String tok = '0BTkTGrLtBgsp35WQZDZD';
        
        class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }
    
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      final bool _loggedIn = false;
      final fbLogin = FacebookLogin();
      
    
      void flogin() async {
        final result = await fbLogin.logIn(['email']);
        final token = result.accessToken.token; // Not used for the the time being
    
        FetchFB data = FetchFB(url: url, token: tok);
        var fb = data.fetchData();
        var fb1 = data.jsonExtractor(fb);
        print(fb1);
      }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: OutlineButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  flogin();
                },
                child: Text('FaceBook'),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Update your question with proper explanations of what you want to achieve and where are you getting that exception?

Comment: @ZeeshanHussain I edited, please take a look again. Thank you

Comment: You're still not showing where this call is being done

Comment: i will update my answer once you show where you are calling you fetchData() function.

Comment: @ZeeshanHussain I have update the topic. Please have a look.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPS I have updated my answer.

Comment: @ZeeshanHussain Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait for the future to complete. Also to decode the JSON, you need to get the JSON from response.body.

```dart
    String url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/me?fields=';
        String tok = '0BTkTGrLtBgsp35WQZDZD';
        
        class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }
    
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      final bool _loggedIn = false;
      final fbLogin = FacebookLogin();
      
    
      void flogin() async {
        final result = await fbLogin.logIn(['email']);
        final token = result.accessToken.token; 
   
        FetchFB data = FetchFB(url: url, token: tok);
        var fb = await data.fetchData(); // wait for the future to complete.
        var fb1 = data.jsonExtractor(fb);
        print(fb1);
      }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: OutlineButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  flogin();
                },
                child: Text('FaceBook'),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

```dart
class FetchFB {

  final String url;
  final String token;

  FetchFB({@required this.url, @required this.token});

  Future<http.Response> fetchData() async {
    http.Response graphResponse = await http.get('$url$token');
    print(graphResponse);
    return graphResponse;
  }

  dynamic jsonExtractor(dynamic dataResponse) async {
    return jsonDecode(dataResponse.body);
  }
}
```